# How to find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(1+\frac{1}{n})\sqrt[n]{n!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to find the limit of the following sequence:

$$x_n=\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\sqrt[n]{n!}$$

Whereas that $n!\sim \sqrt{2πn}(\frac{n}{e})^n $.

I thought of using this equivalence to simplify the expression, but I could not find the limit; any help please?

Comment: Write the sequence as $$
\frac{{\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)}}{{\frac{1}{n}}}\sqrt[n]{{\frac{{n!}}{{n^n }}}}
$$ and use $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}=1$ and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539484/find-lim-n-to-infty-fracnnn-frac1n?rq=1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a physicist I may not be extremely rigorous, but as $n\rightarrow\infty$, one has that $1/n\rightarrow 0$, so the $\log(1+1/n)$ can be Taylor expanded to $1/n$ which determines its asymptotical behaviour as $n\rightarrow\infty$.
As for the $n!$ you already found the correct asymptotical behaviour, which is given by Stirling's approximation, $(n/e)^n$ (the $\sqrt{2\pi n}$ can be neglected as it represents higher order correction which is not useful in this case).

So one has:
$$\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\sqrt[n]{n!} \sim \frac{1}{n}\left( \frac{n}{e}\right) =\frac{1}{e}$$
So the limit is
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[ \log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\sqrt[n]{n!}\right]=\frac{1}{e}$$
Hope it helped!

Comment: Your help was really helpful, I appreciate it!